# visual studio 2012 deleting folder on publish

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-config

I'm trying to publish my final project on ISS7 server and it works fine , but it deletes some sub folder of images uploading. So, I have to recreate folders manually on ISS7 server.

Is there any solution to help visual studio know that these folders are required to run my website? Can I define this on web config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just to Add the sub folders to visual Studio project before your publish it, so the visual studio  know that you want these folders.